# QScrollArea children cannot access parent

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qscrollarea

I have QScrollArea with few QPushButtons inside. I cannot get parent() method working on the child widgets so that it returns parent object. I do pass self.scroll as a parent when creating children buttons, but that doesnt seem to work.

Why I need to use parent() 3 times to get to the QScrollArea object? I would expect single parent() would give me just that.

Here is code. I borrowed code from https://www.learnpyqt.com/courses/adanced-ui-features/qscrollarea/ as an example.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QScrollArea, QVBoxLayout, QMainWindow)
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys


class ChildWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(ChildWidget, self).__init__(parent)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print(self.parent().metaObject().className())
        print(self.parent().parent().metaObject().className())
        print(self.parent().parent().parent().metaObject().className())


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.scroll = QScrollArea()
        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()

        for i in range(1, 5):
            object = ChildWidget(self.scroll)
            self.vbox.addWidget(object)

        self.widget.setLayout(self.vbox)

        self.scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.widget)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.scroll)

        self.setGeometry(600, 100, 1000, 900)
        self.setWindowTitle('Scroll Area Demonstration')
        self.show()

        return


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The return of button press is:

```
QWidget
QWidget
QScrollArea
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a parent is not "final".

From [`QLayout.addWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#addWidget) (and the reimplementations of all QLayout subclasses):

> [...] This function uses addItem().

From [`QLayout.addItem()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#addItem):

> **Note**: The ownership of item is transferred to the layout, and it's the layout's responsibility to delete it.

When the layout already set to a widget, the ownership is transferred to the layout's widget (the same happens if a layout is newly set to a widget).

Also, when you use a QAbstractScrollArea descendant (including, obviously, QScrollArea), you have a QWidget used as the "viewport" (the widget that is scrolled inside the scrollarea) which has the scroll area as a parent. When using a QScrollArea, `setWidget(widget)` reparents the *`widget`* to the viewport.

So, the actual hierarchy is:

```
scrollarea
   viewport
       "container" widget
           button
```

If you're looking for the parent scrollarea (assuming you didn't use nested scroll areas, including item views descendants), you can go with something like this:

```
class ChildWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(ChildWidget, self).__init__(parent)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        obj = self
        while not isinstance(obj.parent(), QAbstractScrollArea):
            parent = obj.parent()
            if not parent:
                break
            obj = parent
        print(obj)
```

Answer (score 3):

When you add a widget to a layout then that widget is a child of the container (QWidget) that handles the layout.

In your case, just add a few prints to understand when the parent is changed:

```
# ...
# variable that stores the first ChildWidget:
first_widget = None

for i in range(1, 5):
    object = ChildWidget(self.scroll)
    if first_widget is None:
        first_widget = object

    self.vbox.addWidget(object)

print(first_widget.parent())

self.widget.setLayout(self.vbox)

print(first_widget.parent())
```

Output:

```
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QScrollArea object at 0x7fb699721dc0>
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QWidget object at 0x7fb699721e50>
```

So in your case ChildWidget is a child of "self.widget" at the end of the constructor.

Tip: If you want to know the structure then use the [`dumpObjectTree()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#dumpObjectTree) method:

```
main = MainWindow()
print(main.dumpObjectTree())
```

Output:

```
MainWindow:: 
    QMainWindowLayout::_layout 
    QScrollArea:: 
        QWidget::qt_scrollarea_viewport 
            QWidget:: 
                QVBoxLayout:: 
                ChildWidget:: 
                ChildWidget:: 
                ChildWidget:: 
                ChildWidget:: 
        QWidget::qt_scrollarea_hcontainer 
            QScrollBar:: 
            QBoxLayout:: 
        QPropertyAnimation:: 
        QPropertyAnimation:: 
        QWidget::qt_scrollarea_vcontainer 
            QScrollBar:: 
            QBoxLayout::
```

Where the hierarchy of the ChildWidget and the QScrollArea are observed.

Comment: thanks for that dumpObjectTree(), i was about to ask for it!